# Fill ArrayList in JNI yields Segfault

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I made a very simple JNI application to fill an array. The C++ code should simply insert elements into the list. However, `env->CallBooleanMethod` yields a segmentation fault. The input arguments to this method are all not null. As far as I understand, this should work. What's the problem of this?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("/path/to/project/Main.so");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Main.fill(list, 1);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static native void fill(List<Integer> list, int n);
}
```

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_fill
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject jList, jint jn) {
  jclass jListCls = env->GetObjectClass(jList);
  jmethodID jListAddMethod = env->GetMethodID(jListCls, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
  for (int i = 0; i < jn; i++) {
    env->CallBooleanMethod(jList, jListAddMethod, (jint) i); // <- Segfault occurs here
  }
  env->DeleteLocalRef(jListCls);
}
```

Comment: The argument you pass to `add` shouldn't be a `jint`, but a `jobject` referencing an instance of `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: Interesting, I see. So, JNI doesn't do this conversion automatically?

Comment: No, JNI is very explicit. So it doesn't have things like auto-(un)boxing.

Comment: @Michael Can you write that as an answer so it can be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list elements are of the type `java.lang.Integer`. In JNI code there's no autoboxing, so primitive integers won't get automatically converted to `java.lang.Integer`.

You'll have to get/create the `java.lang.Integer` instances yourself. That is, get a reference to that class using `FindClass`, get a reference to the static `valueOf` method, and then invoke it.